# WSO2 listAdminServices - services showed in the store page

Tags: api, wso2, store, jaggery-js

Is it possible to execute the command listAdminServices from jaggery to show the services list in the store page ?

Comment: Is this what you expect? Please follow this link [1]
[1] http://blog.lasindu.com/2014/08/how-to-call-wso2-products-admin.html

Comment: I already found this solution and this is not fit my purpose ..btw thanks

Comment: Why I received the downvote???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to execute the command listAdminServices from jaggery
>   to show the services list in the store page ?

Currently, You can get this through the OSGI only. And, this is a static list, if you need, you can listdown using OSGI and show it in UI.

1. Enable Admin Service editing carbon.xml found inside [APIM_HOME]/repository/conf directory

   ```
   <HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>
   ```
2. Start the APIM like `sh wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole`
3. In the OSGI shell, type `osgi> listAdminServices`